# Oracle Window Function

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATED_DATE | ENTITY_ID | TYPE
02-MAY-17 | 1234 | A 
03-MAY-17 | 1234 | B
04-MAY-17 | 1234 | B
05-MAY-17 | 1234 | B
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return:

```
ENTITY_ID | DIFF_BETWEEN_A_B1 | DIFF_BETWEEN_A_B2
1234 | 1 | 2
...
```

I'm trying to write a query that will show the time it took between getting the first TYPE A record and the first TYPE B record, and the first TYPE A record and the second TYPE B record, for each ENTITY_ID. There will be more than 2 Type B records but only one TYPE A record. I was thinking there might be an efficient way to do this with window functions, but haven't played with those too much.  How would you write this?

Comment: What Oracle version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method, using conditional aggregation:

```
select t.entity_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and type = 'B' then created_date end) 
        - max(a_created_date) as diff_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 and type = 'B' then created_date end) 
        - max(a_created_date) as diff_2
from (select t.*,
             min(case when type = 'A' then created_date end) over (partition by entity_id) as a_created_date,
             row_number() over (partition by entity_id, type order by created_date) as seqnum
      from t
      where type in ('A', 'B')
     ) t
group by entity_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you may be missing a comma at the end of line 7.

Comment: I'm getting `not a GROUP BY expression` caused by a_created_d on line 2.  Any idea how to correct that?

Comment: @taylordurden .. i corrected the code..it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do this in Oracle 12.1 and above.

Since there is only one row with `type = 'A'` for each `entity_id`, the ordering in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` guarantees that the rows we need for the computation will be the first three rows in each partition. Which means the `DEFINE` clause is not needed; but the syntax requires it (which is why it simply asks that `0 = 0`).

```
with
     test_data ( created_date, entity_id, tp ) as (
       select to_date('02-MAY-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1234, 'A' from dual union all 
       select to_date('03-MAY-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1234, 'B' from dual union all
       select to_date('04-MAY-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1234, 'B' from dual union all
       select to_date('05-MAY-17', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1234, 'B' from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line
select entity_id, diff_between_a_b1, diff_between_a_b2
from   test_data
match_recognize (
  partition by entity_id
  order by     tp, created_date
  measures     b1.created_date - a.created_date as diff_between_a_b1,
               b2.created_date - a.created_date as diff_between_a_b2  
  pattern      ( ^ a b1 b2 )
  define       a as 0 = 0
)
;

ENTITY_ID  DIFF_BETWEEN_A_B1  DIFF_BETWEEN_A_B2
---------  -----------------  -----------------
     1234                  1                  2
```

Comment: mathguy this is great.  Just one possible typo fix I'd suggest--perhaps `select entity_id, diff_between_a_b1, diff_between_a_b2` instead of `select entity_id,`  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs - of course, thank you. No idea how that happened - I thought I copied and pasted... obviously I didn't have the typo in the original (the output is also copied and pasted from my copy of Oracle). Anyway, thanks!